# FLORA2 v1.2 with Eclipse vizualizer plugin

Tags: prolog, rdf, semantic-web, owl, xsb

Just start to play with http://flora.sf.net reasoning system.

Trying to configure
`Window/Preferences/Flora-2 Preferences/Reasoner`

pointing to installed D:\FLORA or D:\FLORA\flora2
have message box

`Did you install Flora-2 with cygwin?`

Eclipse was updated, and plugin was installed from http://flora.sourceforge.net/visualizer

and error

`FLORA-2 Visualizer did not find a configured version of FLORA-2 at a default location.
Please specify the location of a configured FLORA-2 system using the following menu:
    Window -> Preferences -> Flora Reasoner`

*PS: In real I don't need full plugin, **it can be just set of flora scripts**,
which can generate debugging information in visualizable form:
**.dot files for GraphViz is the best variant**, or some set of .svg.*

PSS: maybe InterProlog Studio will be good IDE solution with some tunings.

Comment: so did you specify your location then? because the error says you should specify location of a configured FLORA-2 system using the following menu:
    Window -> Preferences -> Flora Reasoner

Comment: As I understand, Flora runs on XSB, right?

Comment: Yes, packaged with XSB

Comment: Plugin can't see directly selected location, I tested all variants